# Reverse geocode for given lat long gives incomplete address results for iOS app when compared to the GET api

Tags: ios, google-maps, location, reverse-geocoding

In my iOS app I am trying to get address details for lat long (18.557121460659193, 73.793425261974335). I am making use of following code to get address details.

```
func reverseGeoCode() {
    let gmsCoder = GMSGeocoder()
    gmsCoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.557121460659193, 73.793425261974335), completionHandler: { (response, error) in
        if let address = response?.firstResult() {
            let lines = address.lines! as [String]

            let completeAddress = lines.joined(separator: " ")
            print(completeAddress)
            print(response?.results())
        }
    })
}
```

In response, I receive an object of GMSReverseGeocodeResponse which contains results as an array of GMSAddress objects.

the result array contains 7 objects and the first address component received is as shown below

```
some : 7 elements
- 0 : GMSAddress {
coordinate: (18.557121, 73.793425)
lines: S.No.3, Baner Road, Riviresa Society, Baner, Pune, Maharashtra 411045
thoroughfare: S.No.3 Baner Road
subLocality: Riviresa Society
locality: Pune
administrativeArea: Maharashtra
postalCode: 411045
country: India
}
```

However this is not the detailed address result that is received.

When i try to get the location address details using the GET api

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.557121460659193,73.793425261974335&sensor=true

I get the result array count as 10. Also the first address details are something like this

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Omkar Building",
           "short_name" : "Omkar Building",
           "types" : [ "premise" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Baner Road",
           "short_name" : "Baner Rd",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Baner",
           "short_name" : "Baner",
           "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Pune",
           "short_name" : "Pune",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Pune",
           "short_name" : "Pune",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Maharashtra",
           "short_name" : "MH",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "India",
           "short_name" : "IN",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "411045",
           "short_name" : "411045",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Omkar Building, Baner Rd, Baner, Pune, Maharashtra 411045, India",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 18.5572967,
              "lng" : 73.79350599999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 18.5570646,
              "lng" : 73.79327309999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 18.5571293,
           "lng" : 73.793358
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 18.5585296302915,
              "lng" : 73.7947385302915
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 18.5558316697085,
              "lng" : 73.79204056970849
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJD2Vxati-wjsRROyg_2yMD50",
     "types" : [ "premise" ]
  },
```

The first address component shown here is the accurate address which should also be shown when i try to get details using reversegeocode api in iOS application.

I have also implemented reverse geocoding in an Android app and the Android app shows the address details like the first address component of the GET api.

Can anyone please help me in determining why am I receiving incomplete address components array when compared to the GET api and the Android app. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Environment - 
iOS version: iOS 11.1
Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.4.0